# Single or double thesis for double major?

Tags: graduate-admissions, thesis

I am having a double major in my BSc, first one is Electrical and Electronic Engineering and second one is Computer Science [probably it was a bad idea because my cgpa is low, but anyways I have decided to do it]. Now it is time for thesis. Since both of the major are closely related, either I can go for a single big thesis that is something in between both of the courses or I can go for two different thesis. Now the thing I am concern about is that, single thesis or double thesis which one will look good at my Masters Admission Application?

Comment: what will be considered more valuable at my masters application?

Comment: In which field are you applying for a master's? Regardless, my advice would be to write one thesis. Two theses would be a huge amount of work, and it sounds like workload is already an issue for you if your gpa is dropping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Write one thesis*, so you only have to write one introduction and discussion section, and only have to go through the thesis formatting nightmare once. If you prefer two small projects, you can make two projects two separate chapters for your thesis and just try and figure out a way to relate them in your introduction and discussion.

*Make the title of your thesis sound applicable to the field of study you want to get your masters in* (no one will read your undergrad thesis on the admissions committee and I doubt anyone will care whether you wrote two theses or one).

You say you have a low GPA. Perhaps two smaller projects (still for one thesis) will allow you to *collaborate with two different professors*. Why is this advantageous? Because that is potentially two very strong letters of recommendation. Many undergrads have one good letter of recommendation and the rest are just professors that taught a course they took. If you have two very strong letters, that is quite impressive, and will do more to get you into graduate school than anything related to your thesis, short of publishing it in a peer reviewed journal.